# Bind server port to local ip address

Tags: windows-xp, port-forwarding, local-area-network

Here is the situation:

A Windows XP machine running as server - accessible from outside

A device(camera) which is locally(from LAN) accessible

What I need is this - if I access a specific port on the server from outside, I need it to make a request to this camera.

Any pointers to get me started?

Comment: Windows XP as a server? Sounds like a home user to me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any NAT/Router/Firewall between your LAN and outside ?
You could configure your NAT in a way that when there is a connection a specific port, it's redirected to ip x.x.x.x in your LAN